# Regular expression of decimal range 0.025 to 99.999

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I know that dozens of similar questions was asked before, but cannot find solution which fits my needs.

**I need a regular expression as a pattern** for validation purposes, which is a range between `0.025` to `99.999` but should also match integers and any possible decimal forms up to 3 decimals:

> 1 - matched
>
> 1.0 - matched
>
> 1.000 - matched
>
> 0.025 - matched
>
> 0.03 - matched
>
> 0.01 - not matched
>
> 0.024 - not matched

So far my regex looks like this:

```
^(?!0*(\.0+)?$)([1-9]?[0-9]\.[0-9]{0,3}|[1-9]?[0-9])?$
```

It actually matches all between `0.001` and `99.999`, because managed how to exclude 0 with decimal forms, but don't know how in the easiest way exclude `0.001` to `0.024`.

Comment: Is it *required* to use a regex? Because it's quite a lot simpler to not use one and just check if the number is within the range you want.

Comment: @vlaz I need to provide regex patter for validation purposes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this with a regular exression, you need something a bit complex:

`^(?:0\.02[5-9]|0\.0[3-9]\d?|0\.[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.\d{1,3})?)$`

[Here it is in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/AdDFc6/4)

Here is how this works in JS

```js
const regex = /^(?:0\.02[5-9]|0\.0[3-9]\d?|0\.[1-9]\d{0,2}|[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.\d{1,3})?)$/;

const testValues = [ "0", "1", "99.999", "0.025", "0.024", "0.01" ];

testValues.forEach(value => console.log(value, regex.test(value)));
```

Explanation for the expression: it's a bunch of ORs that cover the value range. Although you can compress it more, I've tried to keep it logical and readable:

- `0\.02[5-9]` - values from `0.025` to `0.029`
- `0\.0[3-9]\d?` - values from `0.03` to `0.099`. The last digit is optional.
- `0\.[1-9]\d{0,2}` - values from `0.1` to `0.999`. The last two digits are optional. The fractional part in each case up to now is mandatory, so `0` is not valid.
- `[1-9][0-9]?(?:\.\d{1,3})` - values from 1 to 99.999. Again, the decimal point and fractional part are set as optional. If present, you can have 1-3 of them.
- the entire regex is wrapped in a non-capturing group and then nested between `^` and `$` anchors to make sure that the ENTIRE string matches.

Notable exclusions with this regular expression:

- exponential form/scientific notation. For example: `3e1` or `3e-1`
- numbers that lead with zero. For example: `01`, `02.345`
- numbers that start with a sign. For example: `+10`
- values that start from the decimal part. For example: `0.2`, `0.123`
- values that end in a dot. For example `1.`, `2.`
- strings that contain whitespace. For example: `" 1"` will fail to match. The easiest way to solve this is by ensuring the values are trimmed before being tested.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort @vlaz but I can see that 0 is matched but it shouldn't be ;). Adding `(?!0)` on the beginning will cut all 0.000 - 0.999 range so there should be something else. If you know how to easily get rid of 0 in this case update your answer please. I have been working on my version, maybe not so good looking and short as yours but it works.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise `0` is invalid. I'll amend it but essentially, it's enough to make the fractional part mandatory in the third branch of the regex - `0\.[1-9]\d{0,2}`

Comment: And thanks for detailed explanation, now I was able to build another regex easily :)

Answer (score 7):

in javascript you can just convert the string to number and use logic like this

```
const str = '1.0'
const test = +str;

if(test >= 0.025 && test <= 99.999) {
  console.log('valid');
}
```

IMO this will be simpler and easier to read

EDIT:

as mentioned in comments this will pass for strings like `3e-2` which is valid syntax in javascript to define numbers, so you might have to handle that case based on your use case.

Comment: Just a potential thing - you could pass in `3e-2` and that would be valid because it'd be converted from exponential notation to `0.03`. I don't know if that's acceptable by OP but it's worth noting.

Comment: Deleted prev. comment @ashish, cause I'm talking bullshits. In fact I might probably use number type variables, but wanted to provide regex pattern for reactive forms validation.